# Unknown "stylesheets" tag in Symfony3

Tags: html, css, assetic, symfony

I have tried in Symfony 3 and symphony 2.8 both to use the AsseticBundle CSS and stylesheets but I am keep getting an error ...

> Unexpected "stylesheets" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block"
>   tag defined near line 8) in ::base.html.twig at line 8. 500 Internal
>   Server Error - Twig_Error_Syntax

This is what I am trying to address ---

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
{% stylesheets 'bundles/admin/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have search for the solution and I find that it has been removed from the new version, so if it is removed from the new version how can I address my stylesheet?

Comment: Twig is expecting an `end` block before you opening a `stylesheets` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joshua says follow the the instruction from Symfony  https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#installing-and-enabling-assetic

And just give the directory where your CSS and JavaScript files are --

for instant you have a admin bundle and you want to give the directory, what you do is that you go to your `config.yml` file add the following code -

```
{% javascripts
    '@AdminBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Hope it answer's your question !

Answer (score 8):

The Assetic Bundle has been removed from the standard installation in Symfony 3. You have to install it by hand: https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#installing-and-enabling-assetic